# Deleting and retaining data in a cell array -Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a set of data in a cell array ,a part of which is shown below.The first three columns of row 2 and row 3 are same.In the 2nd row from columns 4 onwards it contains P0702 which is already captured in row 3(with the same first three columns as row 2).So i would like the delete the 2nd row.Similarly 5 and 6th rows have same data in the first three columns.P0882 and P0702 in the fifth row is also present in the sixth row,so i would want to delete the 5th row .

Data before duplicates

```
'1FA'   2   'Fm'    []      []      []      []      []  []  []  'P2700' []
'1Fc'   2   'Fz'    []      []      []      'P0702' []  []  []  []      []
'1Fc'   2   'Fz'    []     'P0702'  'P0801' []      []  []  []  []      []
'1Fj'   8   'Fr'    'P0702' []      []      []      []  []  []  []      []
'1FAH'  2   'Fo'    []  []  []  []  []  []  'P0882' 'P0702' []
'1FAH'  2   'Fo'    []  []  []  []  []  []  'P0882' 'P0702' 'P2700'
```

Data after Duplicates

```
    '1FA'   2   'Fm'    []      []      []      []  []  []  []  'P2700' []

    '1Fc'   2   'Fz'    []      'P0702' 'P0801' []  []  []  []  []      []
    '1Fj'   8   'Fr'    'P0702' []      []      []  []  []  []  []      []

    '1FAH'  2   'Fo'    []  []  []  []  []  []  'P0882' 'P0702' 'P2700'
```

Any help would be great on this.

Comment: When a duplicate is found, always delete the first row?

Comment: @Daniel-Not necessarily ,i deleted in this case because row 3 and row 6 had some extra data (P0801-row 3) and P2700-Row 6) captured when compared to row 2 and row 5.

Comment: Keep always the row which contains the most nonempty cells?

Answer (score 0):

First reading the question I thought this should be possible in 2 or 3 lines, but it took some lines of code to solve:

```
M={'1FA'   2   'Fm'    []      []      []      []      []  []  []  'P2700' []
'1Fc'   2   'Fz'    []      []      []      'P0702' []  []  []  []      []
'1Fc'   2   'Fz'    []     'P0702'  'P0801' []      []  []  []  []      []
'1Fj'   8   'Fr'    'P0702' []      []      []      []  []  []  []      []
'1FAH'  2   'Fo'    []  []  []  []  []  []  'P0882' 'P0702' []
'1FAH'  2   'Fo'    []  []  []  []  []  []  'P0882' 'P0702' 'P2700' }

%r contains the number of nonempty cells, you want those with highest r
r=sum(cellfun(@(x)~isempty(x),(M(:,4:end))),2);
%Create a index matrix which maps each string of first and third column to
%a double, which allows to use unique.
[~,~,index]=unique(M(:,1));
index(:,2)=[M{:,2}];
[~,~,index(:,3)]=unique(M(:,3));
%fill fourth colum with consecutive numbers, used to restore original
%ordering
index(:,4)=1:size(index,1);
%Next two lines, sort index to have rows with highetst r first
[~,sorted_most_content]=sort(-r);
index=index(sorted_most_content,:);
%Now first three columns of index should be unique and the best choice
%comes first, finally unique can be used.
[~,indices_unique_content,~]=unique(index(:,1:3),'rows');
%use previously appended consecutive numbers to get line numbers we want.
%sort restores original ordering.
unique_content_inorder=sort(index(indices_unique_content,4));
%The data you want:
M(unique_content_inorder,:)
```